# Straightening the edges in tikz-qtree

Tags: tikz-trees, tikz-qtree

I have a tree, which turns out to be a ternary tree. Here is the code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{level distance=18pt,edge from parent/.style={draw, edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}}}
\Tree [.$S$ [.$S$ [.$S$ ( [.$S$ [.$S$ $a$ ] $+$ [.$S$ $b$ ] ] ) ] $\times$ [.$S$ $b$ ] ] $+$ [.$S$ [.$S$ $b$ ] $\times$ [.$S$ $a$ ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
```

with output:

[image: output]

I want to somehow modify the code to straighten the middle edges from the S at the 0 and 1 levels of the tree. I read up the documentation, and searched for a possible solution, but did not come across any.

Comment: Try with `qtree`  instead  of  `tikz-qtree`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you are willing to change to [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest), here's an option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
  math content,
  s sep+=5pt,
}[S
  [S
    [S
      [(
      ]
      [S
        [S
          [a]
        ]
        [+
        ]
        [S
          [b]
        ]
      ]
      [)
      ]
    ]
    [\times
    ]
    [S
      [b]
    ]
  ] 
  [+,before computing xy={s=(s("!p")+s("!n"))/2}
  ] 
  [S
    [S
      [b]
    ]
    [\times
    ]
    [S
      [a]
    ]
  ] 
] 
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to stick to `tikz-qtree`, here's an option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=20pt},
  level 2/.style={sibling distance=30pt},
  level distance=18pt,
  edge from parent/.style={
    draw, 
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}
  }
}
\Tree 
[.\node[name=S0] {$S$}; 
  [.\node[name=S1left] {a$S$}; 
    [.\node[name=S2left] {b$S$}; ( [.$S$ [.$S$ $a$ ] \node {$+$}; [.$S$ $b$ ] ] ) ] 
    [.$S$ $b$ ] 
  ] 
  [.$S$ [.$S$ $b$ ] $\times$ [.$S$ $a$ ] ] 
]
\node (add1) at (S0|-S1left) {$+$};
\node (add2) at (S1left|-S2left) {$\times$};
\draw (S0) -- (add1);
\draw (S1left) -- (add2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't see the other option, yet. The one pertaining to `tikz-qtree`.

Comment: @Paramjit Do you see it now?